# QSqlQuery возвращает некоректные данные

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt5

Здравствуйте. Третий день бьюсь над проблемой.

1. Элемент списка `query.exec` - запрос не воспринимает русские буквы в названии таблицы.
2. При обращении к таблице с полями, которые содержат кириллицу, запрос возвращает "". На `5.3` возвращал кириллицу, которая была написана заглавными буквами.
3. `db.tables()` возвращает название таблиц на русском.

> ОС: Debian 8
>   Qt: 5.7
>   СУБД: Sql server

Кодировка БД `latin1`.

```
SqlQuery query;
query.exec("SELECT Название FROM table1");
while(query.next())
    qDebug << query.value(0).toString();
```

Comment: Укажите СУБД, прописана ли локаль в коннекте? Как прописана локаль в коннекте?

Comment: СУБД mssql-server_14.0.1.246-6_amd64.deb

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase :: addDatabase ("QODBC"); <br>

db.setUserName("SA");

db.setHostName ("localhost");

db.setPort (1433);

db.setPassword ("Pass");

Comment: А почему у вас кодировка latin? Поставьте win1251 или utf-8.